# Access Requests Unable To Approve

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, access

I am the Site Collection Admin of a site that has a couple pending requests for access. Usually, there is a context menu you can click then select Approve or Deny. It doesn't appear under this screen anymore so I have no way to approve the user's access.

[image: AccessRequests]

Has anyone seen this for an SCA? What is a workaround for approval besides adding them manually?

Comment: We are also encountering the same issue in our tenant

Comment: @mheptinstall just on classic or modern or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a current bug, see advisory message SP207180 that is posted in the Office 365 admin center and suggested workaround:

> Title: All admins may be unable to address access requests for classic
>   SharePoint Online sites in admin center
>
> User Impact: Admins are unable to approve or deny access requests to
>   classic sites in the SharePoint Online admin center.
>
> More info: The approve and deny buttons aren’t populating.
>
> **As a workaround, admins can sort the users requests using any field
>   and the accept/ decline buttons will populate.**
>
> Current status: We've validated a code fix for this issue and expect
>   deployment to complete by Monday, March 30, 2020.
>
> Scope of impact: This issue may affect any admin attempting to approve
>   or deny user access requests to classic SPO sites through the SPO
>   Admin center.
>
> Estimated time to resolve: We expect deployment to be completed on
>   Monday, March 30, 2020.
>
> Root cause: A recent deployment caused the accept/ decline button not
>   to populate for admins within the SPO admin center.

Answer (score 0):

Check who will receive access requests for the site.

Set up and manage access requests for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3

Answer (score 0):

As mheptinstall said, this issue is reported in Office 365 admin center-> Service health.

As a workaround, admins can sort the users requests using any field and the accept/ decline buttons will populate.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54493e83-7ff8-4f0f-99c4-9f25932cbb07/sharepoint-online-access-requests?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious